# incompatible types when assigning pointers-to-records to pointer-fields of other records

Tags: pointers, pascal, incompatibility

I am trying to implement a simple queue program in Pascal. This is the code:

```
type

tree = record 
      symbol: char;
      lt, rt: ^tree;
       end;

element = record
         load : ^tree;
         nxt : ^element;
         prv : ^element;
      end;

queue = record
       first : ^element;
       last  : ^element;
    end;     

procedure element_init(var e : element);
begin
   e.nxt := nil;
   e.prv := nil;
end;

procedure queue_init(var q : queue);
begin
   q.first := nil;
   q.last := nil;
end;

function queue_empty(var q :  queue): boolean;
begin
   queue_empty := q.first = nil;
end;

procedure queue_append(var q : queue; var e : element);
begin
   if queue_empty(q) then
   begin
      q.first := e;
   end
   else
   begin
      e.prv := q.last;
      q.last := e;
   end;
end;
```

The queue is a doubly linked list of elements that are records that contain as their load a pointer to a type `tree`. The issue with this code is here:

```
procedure queue_append(var q : queue; var e : element);
begin
   if queue_empty(q) then
   begin
      q.first := e;
   end
   else
   begin
      e.prv := q.last;
      q.last := e;
   end;
end;
```

I am getting `Error: Incompatible types: got "element" expected "queue.^element"`

Why? I have defined `queue` to have a field `first` which is of type `^element`. I pass the function a `queue` pointer and a `element` pointer. Then I assign the element pointer to the element-pointer-field `first` of `queue`... why is this mechanically incorrect?

## Edit

changed the function according to comment:

```
procedure queue_append(var q : queue; e : elementPtr);
begin
   if queue_empty(q) then
   begin
      q.first := e;
   end
   else
   begin
      e.prv := q.last;
      q.last := e;
   end;
end;
```

with a preceding definition:

`elementPtr = ^element;`

Comment: Pascal is strictly typed, and a *pointer to element* (`^element`) is not the same as `var e: element`. You should make your code cleaner and declare the appropriate pointer types (for instance `type PElement = ^element`) and use the strict types where they belong. It also makes your code cleaner.

Comment: Okay, I see. I changed it accordingly, but what do I do with this line `e.prv := q.last;` ? That is still throwing an error, and I don't quite see why. `Error: Illegal qualifier
Error: Illegal expression
Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "identifier PRV" found`

Comment: nevermind, I forgot to dereference, sry.